# Zappa: authorize my stack for AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: aws-lambda, zappa

I have just started using Zappa to run apps in AWS Lambda. My function uses a MySQL database and I keep the username & password in the AWS Secrets Manager. There is no problem storing the ARN of the secret in an INI file that is part of the lambda system. However, I need to authorize my Lambda instance to use the secret and secrets manager. Is there any way to do this by default, in the zappa_settings.json file, for example? Or do I need to manually add it to the AWS console?